# How to force the Service Worker to update the app on page load

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Is it possible to fetch a new version of an app with service worker and display it immediately.
Timetable:

- new version is available on the server
- a user visits the page
- the service worker is refreshing all data from the server
- the user gets the latest content without needing to reload the page

I have seen a comment, that the user needs to confirm the page reload, is that really needed?
-> Update:  No it is not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model in which you describe is one in which the service worker always goes [network-first](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#network-falling-back-to-cache), and doesn't display any cached content by default. You wouldn't end up precaching anything in this scenario.

You lose the [performance gains](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/high-performance-loading) that you would get from going cache-first. The advantage vs. not having a service worker at all is that you would at least be able to fall back on the cached content when the network is completely unavailable, instead of the browser displaying a generic offline error page.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to provide the user with the latest version available immediately, to do that you should tell the user that a new version is available through an alert box or a toast that allows him to trigger a page reload (button). You should already have the updated service worker installing by sending a message to the SW telling him to `skipWaiting()` that way you can be sure that the page reload will be guaranteed to deliver the newest version of your assets.